# Flatten a object data using Mongo Migration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a mongo collection called `fruit-data`.in there i have document look like this.

```
{
  name:Apple,
  weight:100g,
  color:red,
  other_data:{
   havested_by:Jhone,
   havested_from:Rileys Farm,
   city: Oak Glen, California,
   country:USA
 }
}
```

I want to remove the nested object and get that data to the same level. using mongo migration. I'm using `migrate-mongo` library.

```
{
   name:Apple,
   weight:100g,
   color:red,
   havested_by:Jhone,
   havested_from:Rileys Farm,
   city: Oak Glen, California,
   country:USA
 }
```

The only thing I know. I have to write up() function this. I'm very new to backend.is there mongo specific way to do this?

I have managed to write up a function that looks like this.

```
up(db, client) {
    return db.collection('fruit-data')
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- check condition if `other_data` field exists true
- set all object's field and unset `other_data` object

```
db.collection('fruit-data').update(
  { other_data: { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: {
      havested_by: "$other_data.havested_by",
      havested_from: "$other_data.havested_from",
      city: "$other_data.city",
      country: "$other_data.country"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "other_data"
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xREcJLeuU1y)

---

Second option without hardcoding properties,

- `$mergeObjects` to merge root document with `other_data`'s fields
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merged object to root
- unset `other_data` object

```
db.collection('fruit-data').update(
  { other_data: { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$other_data"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "other_data"
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F0D4GQK4E9f)

Comment: is there any way to get all the data in the other_data object. without hardcoding the property names. because my actual other_data object has like 20 properties.